# Did a merge to master on BitBucket website and now commits are missing in local master

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitkraken

Company is new to Git and did our first pull request but something went wrong.  I went onto the bit bucket website and started a new pull request to merge my dev branch into master (both branches are in same repo).

After pull request was approved, I clicked merge and all seemed to go well.  I was expecting that I once I went back into GitKraken I would see my local master as behind by X number of commits and that a pull was needed.  However it didn't show me as behind at all.  I clicked the pull-rebase option to see what would happen but GitKraken said master had not moved and was up to date.

I did see **some** of my merged commits in my local copy of master **but not all** of them.  So then I surmise maybe to just blow away my local copy of master and pull it all down again from the cloud.

So under the "Local" section in GitKraken I switch to a different branch, delete my local master and then under the "Remotes" section in GitKraken I double-click on master, thinking that it will start pulling down from the cloud, instead it instantly displays a master branch under "Local".

It didn't pull anything down from the cloud at all, if it had I would have seen the progress spinner since the repo is pretty big.  And sure enough in the new local master some of my commits are missing.

In hindsight I'm guessing I should have used my local branches to initiate the pull request, did the merge between my local dev and local master and then pushed local master to origin master.

So how do I get my local copy of master to match the cloud version which has all of the merged commits from the pull request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could never figure out how to pull the merged commits from origin into my local master branch so ended up creating a new folder and cloned the repo into it.